# Why parseFloat.replace is not a function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

If I write

```
console.log(parseFloat(123.123).replace(/,./g, ''))
```

It return

```
Uncaught TypeError: parseFloat(...).replace is not a function
```

But if I write

```
console.log(parseFloat(123.123).toFixed(0).replace(/,./g, ''))
```

It works. So why parseFloat need toFixed to use replace()? Thanks

Comment: because parseFloat returns a Number, not a String. the toFixed is a Number method that turns returns a string. Strings have the `replace` method

Comment: `Number#replace` does not exist. `String#replace` replace exists and therefore you need to convert the numer to a string in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

toFixed(0) convert a Number to String type. Number prototype don't have replace method when String jas